# Combine 3 queries for different lists into one

Tags: caml-query, caml

I am building API for client side apps. There are 3 API requests for 3 different lists as following:

```
tasksQuery = string.Format(@"<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + FromDate + "</Value></Geq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='TaskCompleted' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='CreatedBy' /><Value Type='Text'>" + LoggedUser + "</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Responsible' /><Value Type='Text'>" + LoggedUser + "</Value></Eq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Accountable' /><Value Type='Text'>" + LoggedUser + "</Value></Eq><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name='Consulted' /><Value Type='Note'>" + LoggedUser + "</Value></Contains><Contains><FieldRef Name='Informed' /><Value Type='Note'>" + LoggedUser + "</Value></Contains></Or></Or></Or></Or></And></And></Where>")

meetingQuery = string.Format(@"<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + FromDate + "</Value></Geq><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Organizer' /><Value Type='Text'>" + LoggedUser + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Creator' /><Value Type='Text'>" + LoggedUser + "</Value></Eq></Or></And></Where>")

newsQuery = string.Format(@"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>1</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='NewsArticleDate' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
```

How can I combine all these queries in one query?

Answer (score 1):

You're not able to combine those queries into a single CAML-query but you can query all those items in the same request, ex:

```
List tasksList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
List meetingList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Meeting");
List newsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("News");

CamlQuery tasksQuery = new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = '...' };
CamlQuery meetingQuery = new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = '...' };
CamlQuery newsQuery = new CamlQuery() { ViewXml = '...' };

var tasksItems = tasksList.GetItems(tasksQuery);
var meetingItems = tasksList.GetItems(meetingQuery);
var newsItems = tasksList.GetItems(newsQuery);

context.Load(tasksItems); 
context.Load(meetingItems);
context.Load(newsItems);

context.ExecuteQuery(); 

// Here you can use results of all those queries
```